# Python - How to change the default os.sep?

Tags: python

I'm working with different path functions like **os.path.join, os.path.normalize or os.walk** but not getting the desired paths. I want to get the **'/'** separator in paths. Can I change the default separator which is used by os.sep or is their a way to tell path functions, which **sep/altsep** to use?
My code is like this:

```
dataset_dir = './dataset'
for paths,subdir,files in os.walk(dataset_dir):
    for file in files:
        print(os.path.join(paths, file))
        #here i want a path like './dataset/abc_dir/xyz.jpg
        #but I'm getting ./dataset\abc_dir\xyz.jpg
```

Comment: Look at `pathlib`. That allows you to specify that you want a `PosixPath` or a `WindowsPath` object. That is likelier to be much safer than fiddling with `os.sep`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the modules `posixpath` respectivelly `ntpath` for specific path formats.

```py
>>> import posixpath
>>> posixpath.join('path', 'file')
'path/file'

>>> import ntpath
>>> ntpath.join('path', 'file')
'path\\file'
```

You can also take a look at the [PurePaths](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pure-paths) provided by pathlib. Since they don't actually access the filesystem you can use them independent of the underlying system.

```py
>>> from pathlib import PurePosixPath, PureWindowsPath
>>> print(PureWindowsPath('path', 'file'))
hello\world
>>> print(PurePosixPath('path', 'file'))
hello/world
```

Comment: I'm Sorry for inconvenience. Your Answer is very good. I added some code to my question, can you please help me as per my code? Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadUmarFarooq: It looks like everything in this answer still applies. It's not clear what else you were looking for.

Comment: @MuhammadUmarFarooq Try to change `os.path.join(paths, file)` with `posixpath.join(paths, file)` after importing `posixpath` instead of `os`.

Comment: @Querenker I tried but not got the desired result. The reason is paths contain the string './dataset\abc_dir' and when we combine it with the file xyz.jpg it gives './dataset\abc_dir/xyz.jpg'

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Sir, can you Please guide me as per my code. I'm sorry but I'm not getting.

Comment: @MuhammadUmarFarooq Which operation system do you use? I have doubts that a path returned by `os.walk` contains slashes (`/`) as well as backslashes (`\`).

Comment: I'm using Windows 10